# Flagged a question, now how to change the flag?

Tags: support, flagging

I was reviewing [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70861/selecting-1-colour-in-image-trace-without-clicking-endlessly) and flagged it as off-topic. A few minutes later I actually found an earlier duplicate, much better formulated and with better answers. I tried opening the "flag" menu again, but the "duplicate" flag is greyed out and I get the "you have already raised this type of flag" message.

Why can't I change it within a few minutes of noticing my mistake?

[image: Can't change flag]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, I suppose you can't 'change' your flag once it's submitted. In a case like this, I'd just hit the 'moderator intervention' reason and explain what's up. We can then fix things for you.

Comment: I have been known to do this for a change of heart. And once for a wrongfully flagged Q.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think mods can change the flag anyway (correct me if I'm wrong @mods). If you find a duplicate after you've already flagged a close reason, the best option is to just leave a comment like:

```
"Possible duplicate of [question title](question url)"
```

When it shows up in the review queue it should show that as a possible dupe (I think), at the very least it is visible to anyone voting to close (either through review or directly from the question).